# HTML 5 localstorage AES encryption issue

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, aes

I am using below url for my AES encryption.
https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js

Here, the input text is converted into encryptedBytes for encryption text data.
I am planning to use this for setting the localstorage value.
The issue is am getting the encrypted data in byte array format.
Is there any way to convert this back to some text, so that I can store this value and when I retrieve i will decrypt this first and then decrypt the original text.
Help is appreciated !

Comment: You could Base64 encode the Bytes in the browser, for example using https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js

Comment: @C14L Thanks ..Its good idea .. but when I store in localstorage what about size ? In general it can ezceed 5MB which is allocated to browser ?